# Batch File - Rename files based on parent name and (sub)folder(s) name

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

Here is the code:

```
for /r %%a in (*.jpg, *.png, *.bmp, *.exe) do (
  for /d %%d in (%CD%) do (
    set newname=%%~nd%~x1
    ren "%%~a" "!newname!%%~Xa"
    echo media file in %%~fa renamed to "!newname!%%~Xa"
  )
)
```

The main problem is that the files in the subfolders end up with filename as the parent directory name i run the bat file from.

Example of what happens:

```
C:\parent\name.jpg renamed to C:\parent\parent.jpg
C:\parent\child\name.jpg renamed to C:\parent\child\parent.jpg
C:\parent\child1\child2\name.jpg renamed to C:\parent\child1\child2\parent.jpg
```

I need:

```
C:\parent\1.jpg rename to C:\parent\parent.jpg
C:\parent\child\1.jpg rename to C:\parent\child\child.jpg
C:\parent\child1\child2\name.jpg renamed to C:\parent\child1\child2\child2.jpg
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will echo the ren commands to the screen.
Remove the `echo` keyword to make it actually perform the renames.

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.jpg *.png *.bmp *.exe) do for %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do echo ren "%%~a" "%%~nxb%%~xa"
pause
```

The first %%a FOR command returns each filespec recursively and the format of each file is:
`c:\path\to\folder\filename.ext`

The second %%b FOR is given the `c:\path\to\folder` portion and `\.` is added to the end making it `c:\path\to\folder\.` which resolves to the current directory of `to` and making it interpret `folder` as the filename.

So the `%%~nxb` returns the filename and extension of %%b which is `folder` in this case, and that is used in the rename command.  `%%~xa` returns the .extension of the %%a string.

I hope that's fairly clear, along with examining the code.

The last page of the `FOR /?` help describes the metavariables.

Comment: Well that worked just fine in a line of code. Do you want to explain the commands a bit?

Comment: Hi, indeed it working well, instead of rename is there a way to add the folder name BEFORE the file name? Thanks